# react owl carousel is hiding after when I refreshing page

Tags: reactjs, owl-carousel

I am using the react-owl-carousel package and when I refresh the page, the carousel disappears. What should I do?

```
<OwlCarousel
                items={3}
                className="owl-theme"
                loop
                nav
                margin={8} 
            >
                {
                    news.map((newsItem) => (
                        <NewsContent key={newsItem.id} title={newsItem.title} text={newsItem.text.substring(0, 150)} id={newsItem.id} datetime={newsItem.createdDate.split('T')[0]} />
                    ))

                }
            </OwlCarousel>
```

Comment: could you create a sandbox? or provide full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
{
news &&(
<OwlCarousel
                items={3}
                className="owl-theme"
                loop
                nav
                margin={8} 
            >
                {
                    news.map((newsItem) => (
                        <NewsContent key={newsItem.id} title={newsItem.title} text={newsItem.text.substring(0, 150)} id={newsItem.id} datetime={newsItem.createdDate.split('T')[0]} />
                    ))

                }
            </OwlCarousel>
)
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate with an explanation of the change and why it might fix the issue